# Basis relation to matrices on echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have a question regarding bases and their relationship to matrices. So I know that for a given subspace spanned by $\left< V_1,V_2,...,V_n \right>$ the  lines different from zero of the echelon form of the matrix, where the lines are the vectors that span the subspace, constitute a basis of the subspace.

Basically my question is, how do I know the various different bases for a given subspace? Supose I got an echelon form of a matrix, in the conditions mentioned above (vectors spanning are the lines) and now I know their basis. However there are other vectors that constitute a basis too. My book exemplifies it by giving a certain sequence of vectors that span a subspace, and we get a certain matrix on echelon form. Then, it assumes another vector on the sequence and we get the same echelon matrix.

However, the echelon form of a matrix is not unique, so how do I know if I tried another vector and got a different echelon form, it doesn't span the same subspace? Certainly I cannot conclude that from rank, as it only gives the dimension of a subspace, and there could be lots of different subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, at least from what I understood.
Hope someone could clarify this for me. Thanks.

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand the question that is being asked here. My best guess at what you're asking is this: "if I am given two matrices, how can I check whether the subspace spanned by the rows of each matrix is the same?" Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes that is correct. My book shows that if the differente matrices have same echelon form than the subspace is the same, however it only makes sense to me if and only if the reduced echelon form is equal!

Comment: If two matrices have the same echelon form (not necessarily reduced row echelon form), then their rows span the same subspace. It is also true that two matrices of the same size will have the same row span if and only if their reduced row echelon form is the same. Are you saying that these two facts are somehow contradictory?

Comment: I think so, but only from my understanding. I don't see why the first sentence holds true, from my limited knowledge

Comment: So both these statements are indeed true, and I don't understand why you think that the statements are inconsistent. The first statement is true for the same reason that we can say that "**if** two matrices have the same reduced row echelon form, then their row span is the same": if two matrices have a common echelon form, then they must also have the same reduced row echelon form.

Comment: But couldn't it be the case where two matrices have different echelon forms but the same reduced echelon form? So we got the matrices and they have different echelons and we mistakenly concluded that they span different subspaces? Also you were right, It made sense what you said, wasn't thinking about that characteristic

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you can reduce two matrices and obtain the same echelon form, then they have the same row space. However, if you reduce two matrices and obtain distinct echelon forms, then you cannot make a conclusion about the row spaces. In other words, two matrices will have the same row space **if** the two echelon forms obtained are the same, but not **only if** the echelon forms are the same. With reduced row echelon form, we have both an **if** and **only if** statement.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up things for me.